# Flow - "Item created" trigger skipped but WF continues

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow

I have a very strange issue. I have created a flow with the trigger "When an Item is created or modified". It is working just fine when I am creating a new item or modifying it. I have added a condition to the trigger to start only when a specific field is empty (I am filling in that field with this flow so I had to prevent cycles):
[image]
It is working fine too.... however every 6 hours the flow starts (without any change to the items on the list!) skips the trigger and fails as the trigger body is null:

[image]
[image]

Any idea what is wrong? The flow is working just fine except this strange fail every 6 hours...

Answer (score 0):

As the condition seems to work fine in your flow, is there any auto-update flow or data connection working on your associated list? If the list gets an update on schedule, that may be causing the flow to run.

Comment: No I do not know about anything scheduled. Also the list "last modified" is not matching with the flow start. There are no modified items on the list but the flow keeps starting every 6 hours.